# Search a datagridview using part details in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview

Having an issue with a search function.

I currently search a datagridview which is linked to a sql table which holds data on vehicles.

At the moment people can type part registration numbers into the search field and as long as they end the search text with a * it will show all with details with those part details.

This has been criticized and they want it changed. I have been trying to work out how, and so far nothing has worked.

Here is my current code for the search button.

```
    Private Sub regsearchbtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles regsearchbtn.Click

    Try
        filter.Clear()

        If regsearchtextbox.Text <> "" Then
            filter.Add("Registration", regsearchtextbox.Text.Replace("*", "%"))
        End If

        LoadData()

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    End Sub
```

I guess the way to do it is to capsulate the entire search in "**"...

I'm working as a VB.Net Junior, so am still learning, but any help would b really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

Something like this `"%" & regsearchtextbox.Text & "%"`

With some care you can place the filter setting code in the .TextChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this as well:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = dgv1.DataSource
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '{1}%'", cmb_clmn.Text, txt_query.Text)
```